# DIV is not displayed on click when page content is too large but working when page content is less

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am popping up a DIV on click button. It is getting displayed when page content is less than 1 page. But when page content is too large , Div Pop up is not working . Please find below relevant code and snapshots... 
Need help to resolve this.

Unfortunately i could not upload this into fiddle due to security issue in my pc please save this content in your local as .html and test it...

**Working fine when page content is less**

[image]

**Div not popping up when page content is large.. PFB snapshot**

[image]

**Here is my CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">

#blanket {
    background-color: #111;
    opacity: 0.65;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9001;
    /*above nine thousand*/
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#validationPopup {
    position:fixed;
background-color:#eeeeee;
    border:5px solid #68ad0e;
    width:300px;
    height:125px;
    margin-top:-62px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -150px;
    -moz-border-radius: 16px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 16px;
    border-radius: 16px;
    box-shadow: 12px 0 15px -4px #000000, -12px 0 15px -4px#000000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 12px 0 15px -4px #000000, -12px 0 15px -4px#000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 12px 0 15px -4px #000000, -12px 0 15px -4px#000000;
    z-index: 9002;
}
</style>
```

**Here is my HTML**

```
<div align="center">

<!--Validation Dialogue box popup-->
<div id="blanket" style="display:none;"></div>

<div id="validationPopup" style="display:none;">
</br>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" style="text-decoration:none;color:#060;" onclick="popup('validationPopup')"><div align="right">close[X]&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div></a>
<br>
<div id="validationMessage" align="center"> </div>
</div>
<p>My Content goes here
<p>My Content goes here </p>
<p>My Content goes here </p>
<p>My Content goes here</p>
<p>My Content goes here</p>
<p>My Content goes here</p>
<p>My Content goes here</p>
<p>My Content goes here</p>
<p>My Content goes here </p>
<p>My Content goes here </p>
<p>My Content goes here </p>
<p>My Content goes here</p>
<p>My Content goes here</p>
<p>My Content goes here</p>
<p>My Content goes here</p>
<p>My Content goes here</p>
<p>My Content goes here </p>
<p>My Content goes here </p>
<p>My Content goes here </p>
<p>My Content goes here</p>
<p>My Content goes here</p>
<p>My Content goes here</p>
<p>My Content goes here</p>
<p>My Content goes here</p>
<p>My Content goes here </p>
<p>My Content goes here </p>
<p>My Content goes here </p>
<p>My Content goes here</p>
<p>My Content goes here</p>
<p>My Content goes here</p>
<p>My Content goes here</p>
<p>My Content goes here</p>
<p>My Content goes here </p>
<p>My Content goes here </p>
<p>My Content goes here </p>
<p>My Content goes here</p>
<p>My Content goes here</p>
<p>My Content goes here</p>
<p>My Content goes here</p>
<p>My Content goes here</p>
<p>My Content goes here </p>
<p>My Content goes here </p>
<p>My Content goes here </p>
<p>My Content goes here</p>
<p>My Content goes here</p>
<p>My Content goes here</p>
<p>My Content goes here</p>
<p>My Content goes here</p>
<p>My Content goes here </p>
<p>My Content goes here </p>
<p>My Content goes here </p>
<p>My Content goes here</p>
<p>My Content goes here</p>
<p>My Content goes here</p>
<p>My Content goes here</p>
<p>My Content goes here</p>
<form id="Reject118" name="Reject118" method="post" action="#" onsubmit="return reject_validation(this.name);"><input type="submit" class="Reject" name="Reject" id="Reject" value="Reject" title="Click here to Reject this product item & send back for Moderator's Review"/>
          <br />
    <textarea name="reject_reason" id="reject_reason"  rows="3" cols="9" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Type Reject Reason Here';
this.style.color = '#8f8484';}" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Type Reject Reason Here'){ this.value = ''; this.style.color = '#8f8484';}" style="color:#8f8484;">Type Reject Reason Here</textarea>
</form>
</div>
```

**Here is my Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">    

//Login validation function...
function reject_validation(f_name)
{
var reject_reason=document.forms[f_name].reject_reason;

    if (reject_reason.value.trim()) {
        if(reject_reason.value=='Type Reject Reason Here'){
    document.getElementById("validationMessage").innerHTML="&nbsp;<font color='#FF0000'>Error: </font> Please Enter Reject Reason !";
    popup('validationPopup');
        reject_reason.focus();
        return false; } 
        }
        else
        {
    document.getElementById("validationMessage").innerHTML="&nbsp;<font color='#FF0000'>Error: </font> Please Enter Reject Reason !";
    popup('validationPopup');
        reject_reason.focus();
        return false; } 
}

        function toggle(div_id) {
    var el = document.getElementById(div_id);
    if ( el.style.display == 'none' ) { el.style.display = 'block';}
    else {el.style.display = 'none';}
}
function blanket_size(popUpDivVar) {
    if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined') {
        viewportheight = window.innerHeight;
    } else {
        viewportheight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    }
    if ((viewportheight > document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight) && (viewportheight > document.body.parentNode.clientHeight)) {
        blanket_height = viewportheight;
    } else {
        if (document.body.parentNode.clientHeight > document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight) {
            blanket_height = document.body.parentNode.clientHeight;
        } else {
            blanket_height = document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight;
        }
    }
    var blanket = document.getElementById('blanket');
    blanket.style.height = blanket_height + 'px';
    var popUpDiv = document.getElementById(popUpDivVar);
    popUpDiv_height=blanket_height/2-150;
    //150 is half popup's height
    popUpDiv.style.top = popUpDiv_height + 'px';
}
function window_pos(popUpDivVar) {
    if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined') {
        viewportwidth = window.innerHeight;
    } else {
        viewportwidth = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    }
    if ((viewportwidth > document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth) && (viewportwidth > document.body.parentNode.clientWidth)) {
        window_width = viewportwidth;
    } else {
        if (document.body.parentNode.clientWidth > document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth) {
            window_width = document.body.parentNode.clientWidth;
        } else {
            window_width = document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth;
        }
    }
    var popUpDiv = document.getElementById(popUpDivVar);
    window_width=window_width/2-150;
    //150 is half popup's width
    popUpDiv.style.left = window_width + 'px';
}
function popup(windowname) {
    blanket_size(windowname);
    window_pos(windowname);
    toggle('blanket');
    toggle(windowname);     
}
</script>
```

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle?

Comment: @geedubb : Unfortunately i could not upload this into fiddle due to security issue in my pc please save this content in your local as .html and test it...

Comment: Your calculation for `popUpDiv_height` is the issue.

Comment: you should use jqueryui or bootstrap

Comment: @j08691 : please correct me where the problem is ?

Comment: Btw, you should be using `<script type="text/javascript">` the `language="javascript"` attribute is deprecated.

Comment: @RCorrie : i have modified it but no use... Please updated code

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/YuGY7/

Comment: @j08691 : you are great ! please post as answer and mention what the problem is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to change the top property of the popup since you set the position to fixed. Just get rid of `popUpDiv.style.top = popUpDiv_height + 'px';`.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/YuGY7/)**

Comment: you are really awesome

Answer (score 2):

You did small mistakes with your CSS. This will always be in the middle of your screen no matter of the size of the page content.

Please look at this DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/3GjpT/2/

```
#blanket {
    background-color: #111;
    opacity: 0.65;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9001;
    /*above nine thousand*/
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#validationPopup {
    position:fixed;
background-color:#eeeeee;
    border:5px solid #68ad0e;
    width:300px;
    height:125px;
    top: 50% !important;
    margin-top:-75px;
    left: 50% !important;
    margin-left:-150px;
    -moz-border-radius: 16px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 16px;
    border-radius: 16px;
    box-shadow: 12px 0 15px -4px #000000, -12px 0 15px -4px#000000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 12px 0 15px -4px #000000, -12px 0 15px -4px#000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 12px 0 15px -4px #000000, -12px 0 15px -4px#000000;
    z-index: 9002;
}
```

Comment: please tell me which line has problem and why ?